# Resizing group of images to fit within container, all with same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a requirement where there will be one to four images within a container set to the width of the window.

The images can be all different sizes.

In javascript I must resize all images while maintaining aspect ratio so all images are the same height and they all fit in one row next to each other within the window width.

html structure could be as follows:
http://jsbin.com/uhonaz/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS like this:

```
img{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

if you want four images to fit on the same line, you can do this:

```
img{
    height:100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    width: auto;
}
```

For an undetermined amount of images, try some JavaScript (I am using jQuery):

```
width = 100/$('img').length;
$('img').css('max-width', width + '%');
```

Comment: But this doesn't stop the images being too wide to fit in the window?

Comment: If there are four images, you can use `width:25%;`

Comment: but if you have both width and height then they won't maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: `width: auto;` tells the image to determine it's width based on the image's natural aspect ratio

Comment: This update doesn't make sure the images are the same height, or do anything if the images don't fit within the container.

Comment: You can't have them all the same height, define a total width *and* maintain aspect ratio, it's mathematically impossible. Implement my code correctly and it will ensure they are all the same height, maintain aspect ratio and all *fit* on the same row. They won't necessarily expand to fill it.